# Error SQL71501: View: [PLTG].[MVW_SAURAV] has an unresolved reference to Column [Process_Key]

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW [PLTG].[MVW_SAURAV]
WITH 
( DISTRIBUTION =  HASH ([Process_Key]))
AS SELECT 
                      A.[PROCKEY] AS 'Process_Key',
                      A.[LOCATION] AS 'Location',
                      A.[INDICATOR] AS 'Indicator',
                      B.[SALESITEM] AS 'Sales Document item',
                      COUNT_BIG(*) AS 'TOTALCOUNT'

                      FROM [PLTG_STG].[ABC] A                                                                          
                    
                        INNER JOIN

             [PLTG_STG].[ZEN] B
            ON  A.[LOCATION] =  B.[LOCATION]
            GROUP BY 
            A.[PROCKEY],A.[LOCATION],A.[INDICATOR],B.[SALESITEM] ;
```

It is failing in build process in Azure DevOps .. don't know where we need to make change because syntax seems valid in visual studio and ssms also .. any help would be appreciated

Comment: To narrow down the issue, please try executing the build from your local machine to see whether same issue exists. If same issue occurs, the problem should be laying on your SQL project itself rather than Azure DevOps. Check whether you have missed some configurations on the project. If the build works fine on local machine, try to set up a self-hosted agent on the local machine to run the build pipeline on Azure DevOps to see whether it can work.

Comment: Did you try to use A.[PROCKEY] instead of the alias